# $\lVert UA\rVert_2=\lVert A\rVert_2$, with $U$ unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How do I prove that, given $A$ and $U$ complex matrices of order $n$ with $U$ unitary, $\lVert UA\rVert_2=\lVert A\rVert_2$?

Proving $\lVert AU\rVert_2=\lVert A\rVert_2$ was fairly easy, but I have no idea how to prove the one above.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: For any vector $y \in \mathbb{C}^n$, we have $\|Uy\|_2 = \|y\|_2$. Applying this for $y = Ax$ gives us $\|UAx\|_2 = \|Ax\|_2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Use this fact along with the definition of the $2$-norm of a matrix to prove the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is unitary, then $|Uy|^2_2 = (Uy)^*(Uy)=y^*U^*Uy=y^*y=|y|^2_2$ for all $y\in\mathbb{C}^n$, that is Thus $|Uy|_2=|y|_2$. (Here, $B^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $B$ for any matrix $B$).

By definition of the matrix norm (as operator on $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the Euclidean norm),

$$\|UA\|_2=\sup_{|x|_2=1}|UAx|_2=\sup_{|x|_2=1}|Ax|_2=\|A\|_2$$

Similarly

$$
\|AU\|_2=\sup_{|y|_2=1}\|AUy|_2=\sup_{|Uy|_2=1}|AUy|_2=\sup_{|z|_2=1}|Az|_2=\|A\|_2
$$
where we have used that $|x|_2=1$ iff $|Ux|_2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

In general $\|TS\| \leq \|T\|\|S\|$. So $\|UA\| \leq \|U\|\|A\|=\|A\|$ since $\|U\|=1$. Now $\|A\|=\|U^{-1}UA\|\leq \|U^{-1}\| \|UA\|$. Can you show that $\|U^{-1}\|=1$ for a unitary operator $U$?